# After upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10 screen hangs quite often

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

I have recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, I am experiencing a lot of problems ,the screen hangs quite a few times the cursor is moving  but nothing  seems to happen all what is possible is a forced shutdown. Also some of the 11.10 themes are not applying correctly  eg: orta oron ..etc
Please help me out on this ,or how can i upgrade it back to 11.10???

Comment: does this always happen when you boot up?

Comment: Does it happen when PC busy (under load), or when idle (associated with screensaver)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).